# Show first JSON data Object without selecting any link using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm trying to build a webpage to show JSON data based on the link we select and i had done it and its working fine. My issue is I need to show first JSON data object before selecting any link (initially).

Plunker Link - http://embed.plnkr.co/SPbvgPhfdeCqZG0yzzeZ/

**My HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<title>Testing</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-route.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="richPortfolio">



<div class="container" ng-controller="adsCtrl">
    <nav>
        <ul class="accordion" onclick="myFunction(event)">
            <li ng-repeat="ad in ads">
                <a class="ad" href="" id="ad{{ ad.id }}" ng-click="select(ad)">{{ ad.title }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="showCase_container">
        <div id="ad{{ selectedItem.id }}Case" class="adActive">
            <div class="description">
                <h3 class="ad_name">{{ selectedItem.title }}</h3>
                <p>{{selectedItem.content}}</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>Description</h3>
                <p>{{ selectedItem.desc }}</p>
                <hr>
                <h3>Dimension</h3>
                <p>{{ selectedItem.dim }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="rich.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My JSON:**

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "cube",
    "content": "cube 1 cube",
    "desc":"orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "dim":"300x250"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Gallery",
    "content": "Gallery 2 Gallery",
    "desc":"orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
    "dim":"300x250, 300x600, 728x90, 970x250"
  }

]
```

**My JS:**

```
// Modules

var rich = angular.module('richPortfolio', ['ngRoute']);

rich.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'adsCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});

// controllers

rich.controller('adsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ads', function($scope, ads , element){
      ads.then(function(data){
        $scope.ads = data;
      });

      // devices
      $scope.tab = 1;

    $scope.setTab = function(newTab){
      $scope.tab = newTab;
    };

    $scope.isSet = function(tabNum){
      return $scope.tab === tabNum;
    };

    // nav redirection
    $scope.select = function(item) {
        $scope.selectedItem = item;  
    };

}]);

//services

rich.factory('ads', ['$http', function($http){

    // after v1.6 need to use .then function to get it worked
    return $http.get('ads.json')
            .then(function(response){
                //alert('success');
                return data = response.data;
            },function(error){
                //alert('error');
            });

}]);

function myFunction(e) {
  var elems = document.querySelector(".accordion .active");
  if(elems !==null){
   elems.classList.remove("active");
  }
 e.target.className = "active";
}
```

Plunker Link - http://embed.plnkr.co/SPbvgPhfdeCqZG0yzzeZ/

Now after selecting the respective link it shows the corresponding data. Need to show first JSON data object before selecting any link.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you click and `a` element you call a function named `select(ad)` which set some info to the `$scope.selectedItem` property and you're displaying that variable info. So, in order to get the some data before click something you should set a default value the `$scope.selectedItem` property. Check this code:

```
rich.controller('adsCtrl', ['$scope', 'ads', function($scope, ads , element){
ads.then(function(data){
    $scope.ads = data;
    $scope.selectedItem = data[0]; //Set default element
});
```

Comment: Thanks, you are a lifesaver. Works like a charm.

Comment: Michael can you help me on adding an active class for the above-selected data.
@Michael Alexander Montero